# How to display bootscreen until userspace is loaded in yocto

Tags: splash-screen, yocto, weston

I'm currently developing a custom image for an embedded system with Yocto. My current boot process (on the display) is: Kernel logo -> Black/empty screen (Kernel loaded, now loading userspace) -> Userspace Application.

For a better user experience i want to get rid of the black screen between kernel and userspace (custom logo is shown from kernel start until userspace is loaded). I tried using pslpash, but it basically just replaces the kernel logo.

How can i show a single boot logo from kernel start to userspace?

Comment: As I know psplash is only way and it has some disadvantage as you mention :/

Comment: Do you know what is causing the screen to go black? Typically framebuffers will retain their image until the frame is updated or the screen blank is triggered. Perhaps the fbcon driver is being activated?